# Usage of python variable "_" in knitr

Tags: python, knitr, r-markdown

In Python you can do the following:

```
5 + 6
print(_ + 2)
```

Where the result of `5 + 6` gets stored in a tmp variable which can be recalled using `_`.

I just tried the same within a python `knitr` chunk in an `.Rmd` document but keep getting the following error:

```
File "/var/folders/5j/_1ts10x512sg_5q_3kzc_c1w0000gn/T/Rtmpdd1M3n/chunk-codeacb356dc5a58.", line 1, in <module>
    _ + 2
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

Is there a way to get this running using `knitr`?

Comment: I believe that *only* works in the interpreter. Just **assign the result** if you want to reuse it - it will make your code more readable and allow you to give it a sensible, meaningful name.

Comment: "_" isn't a command, but a normal variable defined for your convenience only in the interactive interpreter shell that is assigned the value of the result of the last command.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thx, I corrected the title

Comment: @jonrsharpe this does not work for me because I want to set up some questions for an assignment where the "_" variable should be used

Comment: Who has set the assignment? What is it? Are they aware it only works in the interpreter? Are you supposed to be using the interpreter? And so on.

Comment: A colleague of mine set the assignment for undergrad students. I want to transfer it from a .docx to a nice .html doc using knitr. The tasks/questions can/should be executed in the real interpreter but reported with Rmarkdown.